# Javascript function to handle concurrent async function more efficiently

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Consider the following:

- A web application that can have up to 100 concurrent requests per second

  Each incoming request currently makes a http request to an endpoint to get some data (which could take up to 5 seconds)

  I want to only make the http request once, i.e. I don't want to make concurrent calls to the same endpoint as it will return the same data

  The idea is only the first request will make the http call to get the data

  While this call is 'inflight', and subsequent requests will not make the same call and instead 'wait' for the first inflight request to complete.

  When the initial http request for data has responded, it must respond to all calls with the data.

  I am using Bluebird promises to for the async function that performs the http request.

I would like to create/use some sort of generic method/class that wraps the business logic promise method.  This generic method/call will know when to invoke the actual business logic function, when to wait for inflight to finish and then resolve all waiting calls when it has a response.

I'm hoping there is already a node module that can do this, but can't think of what this type of utility would be called.

Something similar to lodash throttle/debounce, but not quite the same thing.

I could write it myself if it doesn't exists, but struggling to come up with a sensible name for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A web application can only have 6 concurrent requests because that's the hard browser limitation. Old IE can only do 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a PromiseCaching, like:

```
module.exports = function request(url) {
    if (caches[url]) return caches[url];
    var promise = req(url);

    return (caches[url] = promise);
};

var req = require('');
var caches = {};
```

**EDIT**:

Let me be more explanatory:

Here is not about caching of the responses, but about caching of promises. Nodejs is single threaded, that means, there no concurrent function calls, even when everything is async, at one point of time, runs only one peace of code. That means, there will be somebody first calling the function with the url `y.com/foo`, there will be no promise in the cache, so it will fire the GET request und will cache and return that promise. When somebody immediately calls the function with the same url, no more requests are fired, but instead the very first promise for this url will be returned, and the consumer can subscribe on `done/fail` callbacks. 
When the response is ready and the promise is fulfilled, and somebody makes the request with the same url, then again, it will get the cached promise back, which is already ready.

**Promise caching** is a good technique to prevent duplicate async tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but I probably wasn't very clear in my requirements.  I'm not after a caching solution here as I already cache the response.

Comment: Also this functionality will be on the server-side express application.
Consider when the cache is empty or expired and you get multiple request coming in at the same time, each request will make this http data GET request.  This is what I am trying to avoid.  Only the first request should make the server-side http data GET request, any subsequent request should not and instead 'wait' for the first call to respond and re-use it.

Comment: I understand now.
Works a charm - I basically used node-cache to cache the data, now I changed it, so it will caches the promise instead.  Had to turn off 'useClones' in node-cache for the cached promise to work.

Answer (score 1):

A web application can only have 6 concurrent requests because that's the hard browser limitation. Older IE can only do 2. So no matter what you do - this is a hard limit.

In general, you should solve the multiplexing on the server side.

Now - to your actual question - the sort of caching you're asking for is incredibly simple to do with promises.

```
function once(fn) {
    var val = null; // cache starts as empty
    return () => val || (val = fn()); // return value or set it.
}


var get = once(getData);
get();
get(); // same call, even though the value didn't change.
```

Now, you might want to add an expiry policy:

```
function once(fn, timeout) {
  var val = null, timer = null; // cache starts as empty
  return () => val || (val = fn().tap(invalidate)); // return value and invalidate
  function invalidate() { 
    clearTimeout(timer); // remove timer.
    timer = setTimeout(() => val = null, timeout);
  }
}

var get = once(getData, 10000);
```

You might also want to uncache the result if it fails:

```
function once(fn, timeout) {
  var val = null, timer = null; // cache starts as empty
  return () => val || 
   (val = fn().catch(e => value = null, Promise.reject(e)).tap(invalidate));
  function invalidate() { 
    clearTimeout(timer); // remove timer.
    timer = setTimeout(() => val = null, timeout);
  }
}
```

Since the original functionality is one line of code, there isn't a helper for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can used promise for prevent duplicate request same time

Example write in nodejs, you can using this pattern in browser as well

```
const rp = require('request-promise'), 
var wait = null; 

function getUser(req, rep, next){
  function userSuccess(){
    wait = null;
  };
  function userErr(){
    wait = null;
  };

  if (wait){
    console.log('a wait');
  }
  else{
    wait = rp.get({ url: config.API_FLIX + "/menu"});
  }

  wait.then(userSuccess).catch(userErr);
}
```